# Do Travis CI tests in the same stage happen in the same instance?

Tags: travis-ci

In Travis docs, it states that `Build stages is a way to group jobs, and run jobs in each stage in parallel, but run one stage after another sequentially.`

I know that all jobs in a stage in run in parallel, but do these tests run in the same instance, i.e. do they share the same env variables?

Say I have 3 tests under a stage.

```
- stage: 'Tests'
  name: 'Test1'
  script: ./dotest1
- 
  name: 'Test2'
  script: ./dotest2
- 
  name: 'Test3'
  script: ./dotest3
```

If I set `export $bleh_credential=$some_credential` in test1, does it get carried over to test2? It seems like it shouldn't, as they run in parallel, correct? If that's the case, can I set a stage-wide env variable, or should I set them every time I run a new test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, jobs are all run on new containers, so nothing in the job process can be shared between. If you need some persistence between them, Travis requires you to use an external storage system like S3. Read more about it here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/#data-persistence-between-stages-and-jobs

I would set the env vars for each job, perhaps using YAML anchors for the defaults: https://gist.github.com/bowsersenior/979804